# Any way to speed up WinWaitNotActive?

Tags: autohotkey

I have an auto-send script which works in 2 steps:

1. It runs a target program, and begins a database update command within the program.
2. After WinWaitNotActive (ie database update is finished) it then runs a second 'search' command in the target program

This is working ok, but it is too slow - up to 10-15 seconds after the db update. Is there a way to speed up WinWaitNotActive? Instead of WinWait I tried using Sleep for 8 seconds, but sometimes the second command ran before the db update had finished.

Is it possible to monitor the process activity, and run the second command once it drops below a certain level?

Here is the code:

```
send !w::
Run "Target"
/'Update Command'
WinWaitNotActive, Target, , ,
Run "Target"
/'Search Command' "Search Term"
return
```

Comment: Are there any other signs of the update completing?  If it takes about 8 seconds for it to finish, and 10-15 for the window to lose focus, what's happening in those 2-7 seconds?

Comment: There is a notification tray icon appears, which gives a percentage complete progress of the db update. The time that this takes varies on my computer, and on a less powerful and worse maintained computer will take longer.

When the update completes, the tray icon disappears, with no visible activity until WinWait appears to detect inactivity (even up to 20-30 seconds later), then run the second command and open the search window in the target program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SetTimer` with your desired interval to check the window status.

```
Run "Target"
; /'Update Command'
SetTimer, CheckWindow, -200  ; this check the window every 200 milliseconds
return

CheckWindow:
    if WinActive, Target
        return
    Run "Target"
    ; /'Search Command' "Search Term"
    SetTimer, % A_ThisLabel, Off      ; stop the timer
Return
```